# Inexplicable error deleting elements from a list after taking them from that same list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am currently having an error deleting 2 elements from a list after taking them from that same list. The problem does not seem difficult, and it is not, but I getting an error that I am not able to explain.

Initially I have two list: list_h (with 30.000 elements) and list_v (with 60.000 elements). The problem here is just to iterate, choosing each iteration between list_h or list_v until both of the lists are empty. The choice between both lists is made randomly each iteration and a condition must be fulfilled: if list_h is chosen, one element is added to a final list and deleted from the list it came from and if list_v is chosen, we have to choose one pair of elements, adding them in the same way as an element to that same final list and deleted from list_v. Obviously, such a pair of elements cannot consist of the same element twice.

The whole process takes a few tens of minutes, but despite the fact that for most of the elements there is no error at all, surprisingly every time I try it, in some iterations an error occurs showing that an element has been tried to be deleted twice. In fact, I print the elements before deleting them to verify that they are indeed not the same, but the function (which follows immediately after printing the elements) receives two identical element that are neither of the two that were just printed.

Example:

```
def add_vertical_picture(pic1, pic2, f_s_order, pic_left):
    try:
        pic_left.remove(pic1)
        pic_left.remove(pic2)
        f_s_order.add((pic1, pic2))
    except Exception as e:
        print('V Error in: ', pic1.show_pic_info())
    return pic_left, f_s_order

def find_nextpic_maxscore(last_pic, orientation_order_l):
    best_score = 0
    best_next_pic = None
    pic2 = None
    for i in range(len(orientation_order_l)):
        score_v = get_2pictures_score(last_pic, orientation_order_l[i])
        if score_v>best_score:
            best_score = score_v
            best_next_pic = orientation_order_l[i]
    if orientation_order_l[0].orientation == 'V': 
        for s in [orientation_order_l[i] for i in range(len(orientation_order_l)) if orientation_order_l[i].id_num != best_next_pic.id_num]:
            if s.id_num != best_next_pic.id_num: 
                pic2 = s
    return best_next_pic, pic2

while len(Hpictures_left)>0 or len(Vpictures_left)>0:
     V_prob = len(Vpictures_left)/(len(Vpictures_left)+len(Hpictures_left))
     if np.random.random_sample()<V_prob: # Vertical photo
         best_next_Vpic, best2_next_Vpic = find_nextpic_maxscore(list(final_slice_order)[-1], Vpictures_left)
         print('Best1: ', best_next_Vpic.show_pic_info(),' -- Best2:', best2_next_Vpic.show_pic_info())
         Vpictures_left, final_slice_order = add_vertical_picture(best_next_Vpic, best2_next_Vpic, final_slice_order, Vpictures_left)
```

And there is more! Every time I execute the program, the numbers of errors that occur changes, sometimes there are only two errors, but sometimes the number increases to 10 or more... How can I explain this?

Thanks you all in advance

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise no one will help you, because we can't figure out based on only your description and the small snippet of your code...

Comment: Thanks the answer, I knew it could be difficult without code but I though maybe I could be able to explain right the problem. I have edited the code part, I hope it is clearer now. There some functions which I am not showing, but they are not part of the problem here.